# How to handle SQL key-value tables from my application?

Tags: c#, sql, key-value

So I have a simple key-value table BillTypes in my SQL Server. It looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| Id | Description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | OK          |
|  2 | Missing     |
|  3 | Maximum     |
|  4 | Minimum     |
|  5 | Error       |
+----+-------------+
```

The table holds different types of bill states. I have another table Items with a foreign key BillType, referring to Id in the previous table.

```
+----------+------+--------+
| IdItem   | Cash |BillType|
+----------+------+--------+
| *        | *    | *      |
| *        | *    | *      |
| *        | *    | *      |
| ...      |...   | ...    |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Then, in my application I get data from the second table via a stored procedure. In this sp, I am not sure if  should select the BillType as it is, a tinyint, or use an innerjoin to return the description instead. The thing is, my application has some logic depending on the BillType, i.e. rows will be processed differently depending on the BillType. Should my logic depend on the Id or the description??

In code, should I have something like this?

```
DataTable dt = ...//call stored procedure that selects the BillType id
foreach(Datarow r in dt)
{
   if(r["BillType"] == 3) ... //use logic
}
```

or this?

```
DataTable dt = ...//call stored procedure that selects the BillType description
foreach(Datarow r in dt)
{
   if(r["BillType"] == "Maximum") ... //use logic
}
```

I am currently using the second way, with descriptions, because I think it makes code more readable. I am however worried about the possibility that someone might change the descriptions and break my application logic. On the other hand, using ids would be less readable(though i could work around this with an enum) and would be invulnerable to description changes, but still if someone changed an id, things would break.

To be honest, we don't expec anyone to mess around with the first table, since we made it specially for this application. Still, I am new to SQL and I am trying to learn the best practices of application-SQL interaction, so I would like to know how experienced people do it

Comment: If someone will make changes in your DB keys you will probaly need to change you your DAL to fit into your BL classes and that why i think that you need to use enum as said @AndreasNiedermair

Comment: An `Enum` is only good if the values are never expected to change - otherwise, a code change would need to take place if it ever did.  I asked a similar question here, which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367776/enum-bound-to-database

Comment: I don't expect changes on neither ids nor descriptions, but who knows?? I checked out your question and unfortunately couldn't find convincing answers.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, as i said, enums would rely on ids invariance, the same way as the other method relies on description invariance. Neither invariance is 100% guaranteed , possibilities of database<->application discrepancies always exist.

Comment: @Pedro You can overcome that issue by adding custom attributes to the enum that reference the `Id`-column, which you target in your sql commands. I would never go for plain strings, neither for plain ids, as they have no descriptive meaning, whereas an enum member is safe and can be customized via attributes (or an external registry). Additionally: why not populate the table from the enum?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, yep, i also considered populating from the enum, thanks, good to know it was not a crazy idea. About the custom attribute suggestion, I am reading about it now, will give it a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider this a comment rather than an answer (I don't yet have enough rep to comment).

I prefer the latter (as you are doing), where I rely on the description.

If your IDs are SQL indentity fields (which auto-increment) Consider the following scenario:

1. You build your app and database in DEV environment
2. The production deployment gets back out and re-run
3. Now, rather than IDs 1,2,3 you have 4,5,6

Comment: yeah, the auto-increment scenario was one of my worries

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it makes more sense to rely on IDs instead of values. After all, IDs should be unique, whereas values can have duplicates/change. Although you are not expecting any changes to the BillTypes table, I wouldn't use the string values, as you suggested.

Since updates/deletes/inserts can still happen in the BillTypes table and you want to be prepared as well as have readable code, the easiest thing to do would be if you define your own enum as such:

```
public Enum BillTypesEnum
{
  OK = 1,
  Missing = 2,
  Maximum = 3,
  Minimum = 4,
  Error = 5
};
```

If something happens and you need to add something to the database, you do it and then change the Enum. It would also work if you delete the "Error" entry and insert "Average". You would not get Average=5 but probably Average=6 or something higher. The enum structure lets you define the values with no problem.

Then you can use it all over your code, not just in this single instance. Your code is modified below:

```
DataTable dt = ...//call stored procedure that selects the BillType id
foreach(Datarow r in dt)
{
   if(r["BillType"] == (int)BillTypesEnum.Maximum) ... //use logic
}
```

This makes the code more readable then before, you dont have to hard-code the values all over your code but just in one place. And if it happens,that you will not be changing the database, then it's just a plus.

Another option would be to do the spGetAllBillTypes  (select * from tblBillTypes) and then internally create a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string,int> dictBillTypes = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

int = billTypeId
string = billTypeText

When you retrieve your data from the child table (the one with the foreign key), you retrieve your billtypetext.

You can then do it like this:

```
DataTable dt = ...//call stored procedure that selects the BillType id
foreach(Datarow r in dt)
{
   if(r["BillType"] == dictBillTypes["Maximum"]) ... //use logic
}
```

...but this is still an incomplete solution, because here, you rely on two things: 
1. that the billTypeText will not change (if it does, you have to change it in the code)
2. that the billTypeText will not have duplicates (otherwise you will get an exception about duplicate key value in the dictionary)

Another option is to turn it around:

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

and do the search based on the value instead of the key. But that makes the code less readable and you dont really gain a lot from this.

Comment: well, avoiding hard-coded values is definitely an advantage. To be honest, the thing here is, for some reason, I trust the invariance of descriptions more than that of ids. You say that if there is any change in the db I just have to go change the enum, which is totally convenient, mostly in projects in which you have control of both DB and app. However, bear in mind that I am working on a large enterprise environment, in which the DB is changed by DB managers mostly, and the app only by me or fellow developers. I am not guaranteed that DB changes will reach me as immediately as I would like.

Comment: Although this is weird (changing the db lists without communicating it with developers beforehand) I imagine, that this happens a lot. Both solutions can be used but none of them are 100% solid.

Comment: Exactly, I hate these ambiguous situations when programming. They are coming often now I am working on a new field

Comment: Just an idea, but I guess it's worth trying: can you persuade the DB people to make the field a normal tinyint without the identity constraint? That would enable them to keep the values the same, but can also cause havoc in the database itself if they are not careful.

Comment: at THIS point, I am allowed to modify the table. In fact I created it myself. So yeah, for the moment I have it as identity because I am using the "Description" solution. In case I change my mind and go for the "id" one, it would be smart to leave it as a normal tinyint. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the ID changing, I would recommend creating an `Abstract Class` to hold the ID values.  This can be referenced like an `Enum`, and it will look up the ID on the first call, and cache the result:

```
public abstract class BillType
{
    private static readonly string c_ok = "ok";
    private static readonly string c_missing = "missing";
    private static readonly string c_maximum = "maximum";
    private static readonly string c_minimum = "minumum";
    private static readonly string c_error = "error";

    private static int? _ok = null;
    private static int? _missing = null;
    private static int? _maximum = null;
    private static int? _minimum = null;
    private static int? _error = null;

    public static int OK
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ok == null)
                _ok = GetBillTypeID(c_ok);

            return (int)_ok;
        }
    }
    public static int Missing
    {
        get
        {
            if (_missing == null)
                _missing = GetBillTypeID(c_missing);

            return (int)_missing;
        }
    }
    public static int Maximum
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maximum == null)
                _maximum = GetBillTypeID(c_maximum);

            return (int)_maximum;
        }
    }
    public static int Minimum
    {
        get
        {
            if (_minimum == null)
                _minimum = GetBillTypeID(c_minimum);

            return (int)_minimum;
        }
    }
    public static int Error
    {
        get
        {
            if (_error == null)
                _error = GetBillTypeID(c_error);

            return (int)_error;
        }
    }


    private static int GetBillTypeID(string identifier)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string")
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetBillTypeId", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", identifier);

                return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also have a `Stored Procedure` on your database to do a lookup for that ID:

```
Create Procedure spGetBillTypeId (@Description Varchar (20))
As Begin
    Select  Id
    From    BillTypes
    Where   Description = @Description
End
```

With this, you can simply call `BillType.Missing` and it will pull the Id of missing, cache it, and return `2`.

(Note, most of this was copy/paste, so mind random errors I didn't catch).

If you don't expect the values to change, however, and you are okay with making code changes if that does happen, you can simply make an `Enum`:

```
public enum BillType
{
    OK = 1,
    Missing = 2,
    Maximum = 3,
    Minimum = 4,
    Error = 5
}
```

Comment: What happens if then add a value to BillTypes table? Although the first approach works, it is just a bunch of code that does the same as plain enum with added complexity.

Comment: @martin You would still have to update it, but the added benefit of this would be if the identity changed for whatever reason (environment changes, table modifications, etc.) it would still be able to come up with the correct ID for the record.

Comment: I agree with your observation. Both solutions work and both have their flaws.  Overall, changing a table like that can become a nasty thing, especially in production, so I think that the solution depends on the actual use-case, which we are not aware of.

Comment: @martin True - no way is perfect.  This is a method I use, as the Dev -> Testing -> Production environments I use on a daily basis will have different ID values for most tables like this.  It becomes a bit of a habit to make the application pull the value, rather than change for each environment.  May not be useful to the OP, but it's an option to consider :)

Comment: I don't have the spGetBillType, but I do have something similar, i.e., in the sp I use for insertion, I take the Description as a parameter and translate internally to id

Comment: @Pedro What if the description changes?